# typeof comparison NOT equal to fails (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: json, string, converters

I'm trying to convert any item within a JSON object to a string.  JSON.stringify won't work because it doesn't convert the individual values.  If its an object or number, I want the entire object to be a string.  How do I test if typeof is NOT a string.  I can't figure out why this doesn't work...

```
if (typeof(value) !== 'string') {
     return String(value);
}
```

Any insights?  Full example below:

```
    var myjson = {
"current_state":"OPEN",
"details":"Apdex < .80 for at least 10 min",
"severity":"WARN",
"incident_api_url":"https://alerts.newrelic.com/api/explore/applications/incidents/1234",
"incident_url":"https://alerts.newrelic.com/accounts/99999999999/incidents/1234",
"owner":"user name",
"policy_url":"https://alerts.newrelic.com/accounts/99999999999/policies/456",
"runbook_url":"https://localhost/runbook",
"policy_name":"APM Apdex policy",
"condition_id":987654,
"condition_name":"My APM Apdex condition name",
"event_type":"INCIDENT",
"incident_id":1234
};

function replacer(key, value) {
        if (typeof(value) !== 'string') {
            return String(value);
        }
        return value;
    }


console.log(JSON.stringify(myjson, replacer));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually isn't a problem with the typeof comparison.

The replacer function is initially called with an empty key and a value representing the entire JSON object ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). Since the JSON object is not a string, the first thing your replacer function does is replace the whole JSON object with the string "[object Object]".

To fix this, check that the key does, in fact exist. Thus, your replacer function will look like this:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (key && (typeof(value) !== 'string')) {
        return String(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

I have a working fiddle of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2n9btfo/2/) as well.